# How can I fix the delay of flutter app during launch?

Tags: flutter

When I run flutter app it delays for few seconds shows just white screen and then the main page is shown. How can i fix it

Comment: Have you tried searching for this? First results online show that this is a startup splash screen - https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/07/flutter-how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app.html

Comment: So I have to do this platform specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an entry in the docs about the launch screen.

https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#updating-the-launch-screen

Basically you can provide an image to be shown while flutter loads. The framework is not ready at that point though, so this is done on the platform side.

Comment: can I run any background code while that screen is shown, something like checking the shared preferences of app